# How to return some HTML file on specific URL - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, routes, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot. I try to return some page, when user give me specific URL.

I have two pages:

```
\src\main\resources\static\index.html
\src\main\resources\static\admin.html
```

Now I have the following pairs:

```
GET / - return index.html
GET /admin.html - return admin.html
```

I want the following pairs:

```
GET / - return index.html
GET /admin - return admin.html
```

I know, that I can create some `Controller`, then I can use annotation `@RequestMapping("/admin")` and return my admin page. But it requires so many actions. What about, if I will have more pages.

Comment: Not understanding what you are trying to accomplish.  If all you want is static html then an Apache Http Web Server can accomplish this.  If you are looking for a dynamic site then Spring MVC with Controllers is what you want.

Comment: @ccit-spence, I have REST spring boot service. Of course, I need return some HTML/js files as well. I need URL likes http://example.com/admin, http://example.com/blog and getting HTML files admin.html, blog.html and so on.

Comment: I would look at using controllers personally. It would help you manage things better. If you do not you will end up with a fair amount of code duplication in the html. Negating the perceived extra code with the controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides creating a `@Controller` defining all methods with `@RequestMapping`s there is another way which is a little more convenient and does not need a change if you add or remove html files.

**Option 1 - if you don't mind that people see .html suffix**

Leave your files in the *static* folder and add a `WebMvcConfigurer` to your project like this:

```
@Configuration
public class StaticWithoutHtmlMappingConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final String STATIC_FILE_PATH = "src/main/resources/static";

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {

        try {
            Files.walk(Paths.get(STATIC_FILE_PATH), new FileVisitOption[0])
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .map(f -> f.toString())
                .map(s -> s.substring(STATIC_FILE_PATH.length()))
                .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\.html", ""))
                .forEach(p -> registry.addRedirectViewController(p, p + ".html"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // add the special case for "index.html" to "/" mapping
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "index.html");
    }

}
```

**Option 2 – if you prefer to serve without html and parse through template engine**

Move your html to the templates folder, enable e.g. thymeleaf templates and change the configuration to:

```
@Configuration
public class StaticWithoutHtmlMappingConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final String STATIC_FILE_PATH = "src/main/resources/static";

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {

        try {
            Files.walk(Paths.get(STATIC_FILE_PATH), new FileVisitOption[0])
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .map(f -> f.toString())
                .map(s -> s.substring(STATIC_FILE_PATH.length()))
                .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\.html", ""))
                .forEach(p -> registry.addViewController(p).setViewName(p));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // add the special case for "index.html" to "/" mapping
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Annotate a controller method with @RequestMapping("/admin") than return "admin" and put admin.html in the templates directory.

Comment: yeah, I know this way. But what If I have many html pages. Should I create many boilerplate controllers.

Comment: You can use a single controller with multiple methods each annotated with different  @RequestMapping